# File writes stall during heavy disk I/O on Linux box

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk, virtual-memory, disk-io

I have two processes running on my box => A and B.

Whenever there is heavy disk I/O activity caused by writing large files to the disk by process A, I see that file writes in process B are stalling intermittently. I noticed that I had the following virtual memory settings on my linux kernel.

```
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 5  
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 0  
vm.dirty_ratio = 20  
vm.dirty_bytes = 0  
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 500  
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000
```

Documentation states that 'dirty_background_ratio' is the percentage of the memory occupied by dirty pages before the kernel background flusher threads kick into action to flush the bytes to the disk. Given that I have 64 GB of memory, this background flush should kick off when the dirty page cache size reaches ~ 3.2 GB and I see that it is indeed the case when process A is writing to the disk.

However, as soon as this background flush starts, file writes in process B begin to stall intermittently for periods of about 10-20 seconds. ***1) Given that this disk flush is happening in the background, why does a write from process B stall given that all writes first go into the page cache and not directly to disk ? 2) Is there any system level parameter to prevent these buffered write stalls from happening ?***

Answer (score 1):

The reason that process **B** stalls when the dirty ratio is reached is simple: Both, process **A** and **B** compete for write buffer cache. A process (unless doing Direct-I/O (`O_DIRECT`)) never writes directly to disk.

BTW: There is a similar stall of reading if you don't limit the dirty buffers: If all buffers are dirty and waiting to be written out, a process trying to read needs "undirty" buffers for the data, but as soon as a undirty buffer is available, it may be "dirtied" (made "dirty") by a writing process.

Using the relatively new cgroups you could introduce per process quota, but that is a rather complex solution. The interesting point here is (among others) that limiting `memory` also limits the allowed buffer usage.